# Comparing a Hex String with a Double

Tags: java, hex, bigdecimal

I'm trying to compare a Hexadecimal String with a Double in a conditional statement. I have converted the hex string from a byte array.

```
double x = (Math.pow(2, 256));
byte[] h = null;
...
String hexString = bytesToHex(h); //converts byte array to hex string
double doubleValueOfHex = Double.valueOf(hexString); //convert hex string to double
```

And then I want to do something like this...

```
if (doubleValueOfHex < x) {
...
} else {
...
```

I have tried converting them both to `BigDecimal` but I still run into problems,

For instance if i convert `x` and `hexString` to a BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(hexString);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(x);

if (a < b) {
...
} else {
...
```

It only says the operator '<' is undefined for the argument types

Thanks for the help

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: *but I still run into problems* - tell us about your problems Matthew

Comment: It's saying the operator '<'  is undefined for the argument types java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: and i am writing my BigDecimals like...

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(hexString);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BigDecimals are not primitives, thus you can't use '<', but they implement Comparable interface. So your code should be something like that :

```
if (a.compareTo(b) < 0) {
  ....
 }
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: i see, thank you